# XSLT looping though XML to check if value exists

Tags: xml, xslt

XML:

```
<amenities>
  <record>
    <thekey>77</thekey>
    <thevalue>Balcony</thevalue>
  </record>
  <record>
    <thekey>75</thekey>
    <thevalue>Cable</thevalue>
  </record>
  <record>
    <thekey>35</thekey>
    <thevalue>High Speed Internet</thevalue>
  </record>
  <record>
    <thekey>16</thekey>
    <thevalue>Fireplace</thevalue>
  </record>
  <record>
    <thekey>31</thekey>
    <thevalue>Garage</thevalue>
  </record>
  <record>
    <thekey>32</thekey>
    <thevalue>Phone</thevalue>
  </record>
</amenities>
```

I need to check each record in amenities to find out if "35" (high speed internet) exists.  The records in amenities can vary.  Sometimes it will have 35 (high speed internet) and sometimes it will not.  I need to be able to check this in XSLT.

Comment: Amir, +1 for the good question. You might be interested to look at several alternative ways of achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to write conditions in XSLT, it sounds as if you simply want to write one pattern matching your condition and the other not matching it:

```
<xsl:template match="amenities[record[thekey = 35 and thevalue = 'High Speed Internet']]">high speed internet exists</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="amenities[not(record[thekey = 35 and thevalue = 'High Speed Internet'])]">high speed internet does not exist</xsl:template>
```

Of course you could also write a template matching the `amenities` element and then use `xsl:if` or `xsl:choose` inside e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="amenities">
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="record[thekey = 35 and thevalue = 'High Speed Internet']">exists</xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>does not exist</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The xsl template matching worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**In the simplest form a solution to this problem is a single, pure XPath expression**:

```
/*/record[thekey = 35 and thevalue = 'High Speed Internet']
```

this selects all `record` elements that are children of the top element of the XML document and that have a `thekey` child with string value, which, when converted to number is equal to 35 and that have a `thevalue` child whose string value is the string 'High Speed Internet'.

**All `record` elements that *do not* have this property**:

```
/*/record[not(thekey = 35 and thevalue = 'High Speed Internet')]
```

**You could process these nodes** by simply specifying the corresponding XPath expression as the `select` argument of an `xsl:apply-templates` (recommended) or of an `xsl:for-each` instruction.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/*/record[thekey = 35 and thevalue = 'High Speed Internet']"/>
```

**Do note that just specifying an `xsl:template` with a match pattern derived from this XPath expression, doesn't guarantee at all that the template will be selected for execution** -- this depends on whether templates were applied (explicitly, or implicitly).

**An efficient, XSLT-only way of accessing all nodes of interest is by using a *key*:**

```
<xsl:key name="kRecByKeyAndVal" match="record" use="concat(thekey,'+',thevalue)"/>
```

The above specifies an index for all `record` elements, based on the concatenation of their `thekey` and `thevalue` children (disambiguated by a suitable separator-string ('+'), which is guaranteed not to appear in these values).

**Then, the way to refer to all `record` elements that have a `thekey` child with string value '35' and a `thevalue` child with string value 'High Speed Internet'** is:

```
key('kRecByKeyAndVal', '35+High Speed Internet')
```

Using keys gives us great efficiency (speed) whenever an expression is to be eveluated more than once.